# Python, Django: Is there a way to edit multiple datasets in one template

Tags: python, django, database, forms

Good evening,

I would like to know if there's a practical or even best way to edit multiple - but variable - datasets inside one single template in django?

Here's an example that might explain my question/problem:

1. The user creates an object and defines a changing amount of subobjects...

   ```
   class Object(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
       sub_objects = models.IntegerField(default=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(12), MinValueValidator(1)])
       date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   ```
2. The subobjects will be created in the background, the names after a certain pattern (Objectname_A1, Objectname_A2, Objectname_A3, etc.) but with empty additional data. This additional data is unknown to the user while creating the object and has to be filled later on...

   ```
    class Subobject(models.Model):
        parent = models.ForeignKey(Object, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
        additional_data_a = models...
        additional_data_b = models...
        additional_data_c = models...
        additional_data_d = models...
        date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   ```

**Now:**

Often the user has the information for multiple subjobjects and of course I could let him/her jump into each dataset separately and fill out the missing data...but isn't there a better/more efficient way? Is there - and if there are multiple ways, which is the best - a way to show the user all subobjects to one object in a single template and let him/her edit them?

Hopefully someone has an idea or solution to my problem!? Have a good night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this idea is practical enough for you, but its something I like to use and is easy! In your html, while printing your dataset you could name them using their ids... For example;

```
{% for object in dataset %}

<input name="name{{object.id}}" type="text" /> Name of the object
<input name="additional_data_a{{object.id}}" type="text"/>  Additional data a of the object

{% endfor %}
```

Afterwards, in your view you can get the request.POST elements and e.g. get the elements starting with additional_data_a and split it. So you'd have the id of the element and you'd know which element additional_data_a you have to update. Give this method a try and let me know if there's anything you dont understand.Hope it helps :)